# Javascript/jQuery uppercase first letter of title with some exceptions?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code adapted from a previous question/answer:

```
var str = $('title').text();
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, convert);
       function convert(){
 return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
       }
 $('title').text(str);
```

I need to add some exceptions to this such as 'and'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question ? please clarify it ?

Comment: You can get and set the title directly. No real need for jQuery there. `str = document.title; document.title = str;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could build an `Array` of the exceptions and check to see if the matched string matches.

If so, just return it *as is*.

```
var str = document.title,
   exceptions = ['hello', 'and', 'etc'];

str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b([a-z])\w*\b/g, convert);

function convert(word, firstChar) {
    if ($.inArray(word, exceptions) != -1) {
        return word;
    }
    return firstChar.toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
}

document.title = str;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzQd6/).

Comment: You should change the `$.inArray` test to `> -1` or something similar since `-1` that's the result it gives when no match is found. (There could be a match at index `0`). :o)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for that.  But isn't there a simpler way with .not or using a filter selector?

Comment: Hi Alex, that's great.  One other thing, how do I get it to ignore the first word?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use css selector:

`.toUpperCase:first-letter
{
text-transform:uppercase
}`

and then

`<div class="toUpperCase">text</div>`

Comment: This doesn't consider the exceptions.

Comment: Sure, I was mainly considering the fact that if it was a div or any other element, you could have the uppercase done without the regex part but simply by adding a class on that element.

Comment: You can't have a class on that element!!